# UNSUPPORTED_MEDIA_TYPE Postman Error - Salesforce Composite Request with XML Payload not working

Tags: rest, xml, composite

I created a composite XML payload to update a couple of fields in Salesforce. Used POST request by hitting this REST service https://test.salesforce.com/services/data/v54.0/composite/. I tried with Content-Type as both application/xml & text/xml, but none of them worked. I might have missed to add something either in the body or headers. Can anyone help me with this failure please.

PS: By the way, if I convert the xml payload JSON, the request goes through successfully.

**Request**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sObjectsComposite>
    <allOrNone>true</allOrNone>
    <collateSubrequests>true</collateSubrequests>
    <compositeRequest_ProductRequest>
        <method>PATCH</method>
        <url>/services/data/v51.0/sobjects/ProductRequest/External_Id__c/PR-0128</url>
        <referenceId>ProductRequest_PR-0128</referenceId>
        <body>
            <Integration_Response__c>Review the Line Items for Failure reason</Integration_Response__c>
            <Integration_Status__c>ERROR</Integration_Status__c>
        </body>
    </compositeRequest_ProductRequest>
    <compositeRequest_SObjectCollection_ProductRequestLineItem>
        <method>PATCH</method>
        <url>/services/data/v51.0/composite/sobjects/ProductRequestLineItem/External_Id__c</url>
        <referenceId>ProductRequestLineItems_PR-0128</referenceId>
        <body>
            <allOrNone>true</allOrNone>
            <records>
                <attributes>
                    <type>ProductRequestLineItem</type>
                </attributes>
                <External_Id__c>PR-0128-PRLI-0001</External_Id__c>
                <Integration_Status__c>APPROVED</Integration_Status__c>
            </records>
            <records>
                <attributes>
                    <type>ProductRequestLineItem</type>
                </attributes>
                <External_Id__c>PR-0128-PRLI-0002</External_Id__c>
                <Integration_Response__c>Validation failed</Integration_Response__c>
                <Integration_Status__c>ERROR</Integration_Status__c>
            </records>
        </body>
    </compositeRequest_SObjectCollection_ProductRequestLineItem>
</sObjectsComposite>
```

**Response**

```
[
    {
        "message": "MediaType of 'application/xml' is not supported by this resource",
        "errorCode": "UNSUPPORTED_MEDIA_TYPE"
    }
]
```

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_composite_composite.htm - JSON only

Comment: @identigral, Somehow this exact XML payload works if middleware sends the same request. For some reason, its not working in postman.

Comment: If true, it would be an undocumented feature. Try reproducing your successful request/response outside of Postman with a command-line client such as `curl`. If that doesn't work, then your middleware is probably doing a transformation to JSON.

Comment: Any reason why you want to send xml instead of json?

Comment: which middle ware are you using?